# file not save in database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i try to upload document and save in directory and in database also
when i upload document it saves in directory but not in database
here is upload document code

```
if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile != null && FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength
  < 102400)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
            string folder = Server.MapPath("~/Docfiles/");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            FileUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folder, filename));
            try
            {
                up.fileupladdd(Txt_docde.Value, txt_dname.Value, 
             FileUploadControl.FileName, Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue),
            Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue), 
            Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]),Convert.ToString(Session["UserID"]));
                StatusLabel.Text = "Success";
            }
            catch
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Failed";
            }
        }


        Txt_docde.Value = "";
        txt_dname.Value = "";
```

and sp of upload file is

```
   ALTER procedure [dbo].[fileuplaod]
   @DocDesciption nvarchar(50),
   @DocName nvarchar(50),
   @Uploadfile nvarchar(50),
  @DocTypeID int,
  @DepID int,
  @UserID int
 as
 insert into DocumentInfo(DocDesciption ,DocName,Uploadfile,DocTypeID,DepID ,UserID)
  values(@DocDesciption,@DocName,@Uploadfile,@DocTypeID,@DepID ,@UserID)
```

where is the problem occur?

Comment: no i did not get any error

Comment: when i set a break point in catch it shows me ecpetion "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: i call sp in function    public void fileupladdd(string DocDesc, string Docname, string file, int doctypeid, int depid,  int UserID,string UploadedBy)
        {
            db.ExecuteNonQuery("fileuplaod", new object[] { DocDesc, Docname, file, doctypeid, depid, UserID,UploadedBy });


        }

Comment: any one tell me plese where is the problem occur

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, you're calling `Convert.ToInt32` on something that isn't a number.

Comment: @user2832406: What about the other `ToInt32` call?  Are the values in Department ID all ints?